# dlltool: Can't create .lib file: libpython27.a: Invalid bfd target

Tags: python, windows, static-libraries, dlltool

I'm trying to build a 64-bit version of `libpython27.a` from `python27.dll` on Windows 7 x64.

Following these [instructions](http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano), I tried:

```
E:\temp>gendef python27.dll
 * [python27.dll] Found PE+ image

E:\temp>dlltool --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k --output-lib libpython27.a --i
nput-def python27.def
dlltool: Can't create .lib file: libpython27.a: Invalid bfd target
```

What can explain `dlltool: Can't create .lib file: libpython27.a: Invalid bfd target`?

dlltool version:

```
E:\temp>dlltool -V
GNU dlltool (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2
Copyright 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem. My MinGw was installed with `architecture = i686`. It was the default selection and I forgot to change it during installation.

The problem was solved by installing MinGw with these flags: `architecture = x86_64, threads = posix, exception = seh`. The Path to `MinGw\bin` must be added to Path environment variable of Windows.